# Delete PDF file in iText

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I am creating PDF using iText

```
 FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=new FileOutputStream(filePath);
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,fileOutputStream);
 document.open();
```

and that particular file is going to save in given path(mention Folder) and path is mention in PripertyLibrary file.

I can see the generated file in mention path. Now I want to delete the generated PDF file from the folder after function.

Please help me out!
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would think Files.delete() would be your best bet. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)

Comment: I tried private void DeleteFile(String actaulafileName) 
   {

  String fileName = actaulafileName;
 
  File f = new File(fileName);

  if (!f.exists())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Delete: no such file or directory: " + fileName);

  if (!f.canWrite())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: write protected: "
        + fileName);

 
  if (f.isDirectory()) {
    String[] files = f.list();
    if (files.length > 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          "Delete: directory not empty: " + fileName);
  }

Comment: Please put what you've tried in your question, as well as any errors or exceptions you are encountering.

Comment: private void DeleteFile(String actaulafileName){ 
     String fileName = actaulafileName;
     File f = new File(fileName);

  if (!f.exists())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Delete: no such file or directory: " + fileName);

       if (!f.canWrite())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Delete: write protected:                            "
        + fileName);

  // If it is a directory, make sure it is empty
     if (f.isDirectory()) {
     String[] files = f.list();
      if (files.length > 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
         
      }

Comment: when I am using  f.delete(); it giving me the error IllegalArgumentException("Delete: deletion failed");

Comment: Thank you Soo much Files.delete() is working good for me...

Answer (score 0):

`close()` all you can: document, writer, fileOutputStream; maybe with `try {} finally {}` or `try (...) {}`. Probably the application keeps the file open.

And then

```
File file = new File(filePath);
if (!file.delete()) {
    ... error
}
```

The background is, that iText uses some partial APIs with with their own `close` method.